# When does trepassing warning expire?

Tags: criminal-law, trespass, nevada

Somebody tells me to not come on their property. When does the warning expire? The statute of limitations is about a year, is that enough?

Comment: Why do you think it would expire?  If someone tells you to get off their property, why do you think it would not be a permanent ban?

Comment: @Andy what if they changed their mind, what if a new owner moved in, what if its too long to remember?

Comment: @bluejayke Then the OP can ask if he's allowed back or not.  Once you're told you need to stay off unless otherwise told later.  If there's a new property owner, they can ask that owner, but until then should assume they aren't allowed back (even if they technically might be allowed back).  And it would be the OPs responsibility to remember they were told, no matter how long ago.  Of course the safest assumption is that you shouldn't enter private property unless you've been invited, that will avoid any issues.

Comment: @Andy yea but the law is that after "a warning" you can be arrested for trespassing, but why should the warning of a previous owner apply for a new owner? Perhaps they have different policies, the first owner didn't allow anyone on, but the new one didn't. Althogh in general one shouldn't trespass anywhere, but can you be instantly arrested for doing it again, if its widely known that there is a new owner?

Comment: @bluejayke I didn't say it would apply after a new owner, but that relies on the OP knowing there's a new owner, which he may or may not know, and may have to risk trespassing to find out.

Comment: @Andy I'm talking about a case where its public knowledge that there is definetely a new owner, like if he knew him personally or saw him post online, for example, that he is moving out, and / or if he saw his house had a for sale sign for a long time, then saw a new car pulling in, or if he checked the public records and saw there is a new owner

Comment: @bluejayke Yes, that's why my original comment said the OP might technically be allowed to return, I was only talking about the case where its unclear.

Comment: @Andy, ok cool, I was jjust responding to the original comment which was: "Why do you think it would expire? If someone tells you to get off their property, why do you think it would not be a permanent ban?", to which I countered, that there could be a case where I might think it would expire, when its obvious there is a new owner, hence our discussion :)

Comment: If I found that you are stealing apples from my trees, and tell you not to come on my property because I like my apples, why wouldn't that apply to the new owner automatically, since presumably he likes apples as well?

Comment: @gnasher729 I think as a practical matter, unless you kept a written record of whom you trespassed and conveyed that to the new owner it would not apply to the new owner.  Perhaps I (the new owner) can subpoena you (the old owner) to come to deposition and swear under oath that you have trespassed the defendant.  But it seems like a lot of trouble and no reward for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [crime of trespass](https://www.leg.state.nv.us/nrs/nrs-207.html#NRS207Sec200) carries with it the "warning" requirement (alternatively, no warning is needed if you enter "with intent to vex or annoy the owner or occupant thereof, or to commit any unlawful act").
There is no expiration for the oral warning, though the warning method only applies to a "guest", defined as "any person entertained or to whom hospitality is extended, including, but not limited to, any person who stays overnight", (and excluding tenants). It is reported that Clark County prosecutors tend not to prosecute casino trespass cases where the warning is more than a year old, but in principle a permanent ban is possible (hence, call your attorney to negotiate a return, if that is the applicable context).

A civil lawsuit over trespass is also possible, and in that case there is no prosecutor exercising discretion to prosecute or not. Instead, the plaintiff can pursue the case anytime, as long as it is within the statute of limits: an oral or written warning does not "expire".

Comment: "within the statute of limits" would be for example some years after the trespass, not some years after the warning, right?